# Order by while inserting data into temp table.is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT S.ColumnName,L.ColumnName ...
INTO #Tempdata
FROM [dbo].[M] M  
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[S] S ON S.PrimaryKey=M.FKey  
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[L] L ON S.FK=L.PK  
ORDER BY S.ColumnName
```

Comment: Based on the syntax I added the SQL Server database tag.  Please tag questions with the database you are using.

Comment: Read Gordon's response. It SHOULD have started with "how do you know it did not work". Because the only way you can determine that it "works" is to retrieve rows. Like a table, rows in a resultset has no defined order if the query that generated it does not include an order by clause. This is a very common mistake / mis-understanding.

Comment: I also suggest you learn to apply patterns when they are needed and useful. Too often the <select into #temp, select from #temp> pattern is applied for no particular reason and only causes more work for the database engine for no/little benefit.

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Period.

If you want to select the data in order, you need to use:

```
order by columnName
```

in the query used for the selecting the data.

SQL Server, though, does respect an `ORDER BY` in an `INSERT` in one important way.  If you have an `identity` column, then the identity will follow the `ORDER BY`.  This can be convenient.  But to get ordered results (consistently) *you need `ORDER BY` in the `SELECT` query*.

Comment: this won't be as simple as you says if the table is partitionned or the storage use multiple files or the identity is not a PK

Comment: @SQLpro . . . Are you trying to imply that `order by` is not sufficient in those cases?

Comment: ORDER BY in a subselect SELECT statement is ignored, even with the trick of TOP 100 PERCENT WITH TIES. Off course INSERT with a SELECT will act exacltly as I say. ORDER BY cannot give the expected order when it is specified in a VIEW also. The only guarantee you have is that ORDER BY will be respected for a SELECT main query.

Answer (score 0):

Especially in tempdb, which is often stores data with multiple files, the rows inserted are splitted across the differents files. Retrieving the data using multiple threads (one thread by file to go faster) will give any combination of mingled subsets and give an impression of hasardous order of the rows.

As it has been said, there is no ways to have an ordered storage of rows in a table, and it is the reason why SQL have a ORDER BY clause !

Comment: *haphazard*? Is that the word you were thinking of?